# Unable to freeze GridView header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider:

```
<div class="row">
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        HISTORICAL
    </div>

    <div id="G1" class="G1">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" CellPadding="3" Font-Size="8pt" GridLines="Vertical" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="Freezing" Width="100px" BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Within the <style> tag I have the following code.

```
.Freezing
{
    /* position:relative ;
       top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
       z-index: 10; */

    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: Green;
    position: relative;
    top: expression(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop-1);
}
```

This code doesn't work. There is no error. However, when I scroll through the gridview the header is not frozen.

How do I freeze the header in a gridview?

Comment: have you try to set  `z-index: 10;` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that too.. I think the problem is that my code is not able to find the cssclass at all. I have Named it "Freezing" and within the <Style> tag the description starts with-   .Freezing(a dot in beginning) but I think the code doesn't use the cssclass description at all.